# How to prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{2x} = +\infty$ with the limit definition?

Tags: calculus, limits

> By using the definition of limit ONLY, prove that
>   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \dfrac{1}{2x} = +\infty$$

I have started to answer the question with

For any $M\in\mathbb{R}$ one can find a $\delta$ so that whenever $0 < |x| < \delta$ and $x > 0$ then $\dfrac{1}{2x}>M$

Similar to my last question just trying to understand how to answer these types of questions.

Comment: Your approach looks good so far - from here, solve for a reasonable $\delta$.

Comment: You need to find $\delta$ such that $0<x<\delta$ implies $\frac{1}{x}>M$. This is equivalent to the set of solutions of the first inequality to be included in the the set of solutions of the second. The solutions of the second are $\frac{1}{2M}>x>0$, for $M\neq0$. Therefore if we take $\delta=\frac{1}{2M}$ that is good enough. For $M\leq 0$ any $\delta$ works since $\frac{1}{2x}>0\geq M$ when $0<x<\delta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer these questions, you have to find a constant $\delta$ for every $M$. One way I like to think about this is making $\delta$ a function of $M$. What $\delta(M)$ can you choose so that $x < \delta(M)$ for all $M$?

Note particularly that this is a positive limit, so we know that $x > 0$, which is stronger than $|x| > 0$. Then:

$$\frac{1}{2x} > M \implies \frac{1}{2M} > x$$

So, let $\delta(M) = \frac{1}{2M}$.